# Java regex: Replace all characters with `+` except instances of a given string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following problem which states

> Replace all characters in a string with `+` symbol except instances of the given string in the method

so for example if the string given was `abc123efg` and they want me to replace every character except every instance of `123` then it would become `+++123+++`.

I figured a regular expression is probably the best for this and I came up with this.

```
str.replaceAll("[^str]","+")
```

where str is a variable, but its not letting me use the method without putting it in quotations. If I just want to replace the variable string str how can I do that? I ran it with the string manually typed and it worked on the method, but can I just input a variable?

as of right now I believe its looking for the string "str" and not the variable string.

Here is the output its right for so many cases except for two :(

[image]

List of open test cases:

```
plusOut("12xy34", "xy") → "++xy++"
plusOut("12xy34", "1") → "1+++++"
plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy") → "++xy++xy+++xy"
plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "ab") → "ab++ab++++"
plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "abc") → "++++abc+++"
plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "XY") → "++XY+++XY+"
plusOut("abXYxyzXYZ", "XYZ") → "+++++++XYZ"
plusOut("--++ab", "++") → "++++++"
plusOut("aaxxxxbb", "xx") → "++xxxx++"
plusOut("123123", "3") → "++3++3"
```

Comment: try `var.replaceAll("[^" + str + "]","+") `

Comment: when you write [^str] in quotes, it takes the literal characters in that string instead of your variable so it will match to anything that isn't the letter s, t, or r

Answer (score 17):

Looks like this is the `plusOut` problem on CodingBat.

I had 3 solutions to this problem, and wrote a new streaming solution just for fun.

#### Solution 1: Loop and check

Create a StringBuilder out of the input string, and check for the word at every position. Replace the character if doesn't match, and skip the length of the word if found.

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(str);

  for (int i = 0; i < out.length(); ) {
    if (!str.startsWith(word, i))
      out.setCharAt(i++, '+');
    else
      i += word.length();
  }

  return out.toString();
}
```

This is probably the expected answer for a beginner programmer, though there is an assumption that the string doesn't contain any astral plane character, which would be represented by 2 char instead of 1.

#### Solution 2: Replace the word with a marker, replace the rest, then restore the word

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
    return str.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(word), "@").replaceAll("[^@]", "+").replaceAll("@", word);
}
```

Not a proper solution since it assumes that a certain character or sequence of character doesn't appear in the string.

Note the use of `Pattern.quote` to prevent the `word` being interpreted as regex syntax by `replaceAll` method.

#### Solution 3: Regex with `\G`

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  word = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(word);
  return str.replaceAll("\\G((?:" + word + ")*+).", "$1+");
}
```

Construct regex `\G((?:word)*+).`, which does more or less what solution 1 is doing:

- `\G` makes sure the match starts from where the previous match leaves off
- `((?:word)*+)` picks out 0 or more instance of `word` - if any, so that we can keep them in the replacement with `$1`. The key here is the possessive quantifier `*+`, which forces the regex to keep any instance of the `word` it finds. Otherwise, the regex will not work correctly when the `word` appear at the end of the string, as the regex backtracks to match `.`
- `.` will not be part of any `word`, since the previous part already picks out all consecutive appearances of `word` and disallow backtrack. We will replace this with `+`

#### Solution 4: Streaming

```
public String plusOut(String str, String word) {
  return String.join(word, 
    Arrays.stream(str.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(word), -1))
      .map((String s) -> s.replaceAll("(?s:.)", "+"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

The idea is to split the string by `word`, do the replacement on the rest, and join them back with `word` using `String.join` method.

- Same as above, we need `Pattern.quote` to avoid `split` interpreting the `word` as regex. Since `split` by default removes empty string at the end of the array, we need to use `-1` in the second parameter to make `split` leave those empty strings alone.
- Then we create a stream out of the array and replace the rest as strings of `+`. In Java 11, we can use `s -> String.repeat(s.length())` instead.
- The rest is just converting the Stream to an Iterable (List in this case) and joining them for the result

Comment: Smart idea your `\G` based solution, love it.

Comment: @nhahtdh I really wanted to post your first solution, but since it was already occupied, [one using CharBuffer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315819/1059372)

Comment: my first Idea was your soultuion 4 (assuming, the split will "correctly" split in case the word is at beginning/end of str => leaving an empty string as first/last in resulting array). My second was (basically) your solution 1, except that I would fill out with plusses and then insert word at positions. but my VERY FIRST thought was that as much as I like using regex, this wouldnt be one of the cases where I would use it.

Comment: @iPirat: Solution 4 is correct in such cases, since empty strings are correctly preserved. And yeah, believe it or not, the regex is actually derived from solution 1.

Comment: An alternative \G solution without backreferences, just fyi: `"(?<=\\G|" + word + ")(?!" + word + ")."`

Comment: I also want to do something like this. Only difference is that I only want to replace the '<' symbols from a string where it also has two known HTML tags <br> and <b> which I do not want to get changed. I was trying to use your solution 3. However I was still unable to catch the '<' symbols. This is what I'm currently having. ` input.replaceAll("\\G((?:<br>|<b>)*+)(?:<}*)", "$1~");`  How can I get this requirement done?

Comment: Got an answer for my issue using negative lockhead. Posting for someone in need: ` input.replaceAll("(?:(?!<br>|<b>)[<])", "~"); `

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit trickier than you might initially think because you don't just need to match *characters*, but *the absence of specific phrase* - a negated character set is not enough. If the string is 123, you would need:

```
(?<=^|123)(?!123).*?(?=123|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/EZWMqM/1/

That is - lookbehind for the start of the string or "123", make sure the current position is not followed by 123, then lazy-repeat any character until lookahead matches "123" or the end of the string. This will match all characters which are not in a "123" substring. Then, you need to replace each character with a `+`, after which you can use `appendReplacement` and a `StringBuffer` to create the result string:

```
String inputPhrase = "123";
String inputStr = "abc123efg123123hij";
StringBuffer resultString = new StringBuffer();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|" + inputPhrase + ")(?!" + inputPhrase + ").*?(?=" + inputPhrase + "|$)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(inputStr);
while (m.find()) {
    String replacement = m.group(0).replaceAll(".", "+");
    m.appendReplacement(resultString, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(resultString);
System.out.println(resultString.toString());
```

Output:

```
+++123+++123123+++
```

Note that if the `inputPhrase` can contain character with a special meaning in a regular expression, you'll have to escape them first before concatenating into the pattern.

Comment: I updated the post with the result of my old regular expression and you're correct that it does fail in two test cases. I will review your code and try to understand it.

Comment: From the test cases, the input string can contain special character, so you need to escape it. With that modification, this fails on the test case `plusOut("aaxxxxbb", "xx") → "++xxxx++"`, since the regex matches from the 4th `x` to the end of the string

Comment: if the string is `43134ababab6544` and the word is `abab`, what is the expected beheaviour? `+++++abab++++++` or `+++++++abab++++` or `+++++ababab++++`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line:

```
input = input.replaceAll("((?:" + str + ")+)?(?!" + str + ").((?:" + str + ")+)?", "$1+$2");
```

This optionally captures "123" either side of each character and puts them back (a blank if there's no "123"):

Comment: Now it fails on plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy")

Comment: By the way, your code passes all the test cases on the site, but doesn't mean it's correct. `plusOut("1233", "3")` returns `++3+`, while it should return `++33`

Comment: @nhahtdh I don’t have an IDE handy, but my last edit should pass your new edge case.

Comment: Fails on `plusOut("11", "1")`

Comment: @nhahtdh that now passes too. Good edge cases btw. I also removed the word *simple* :)

Comment: Fails on `plusOut("abc", "abc")`. I'm wondering why this isn't a test case in the set.

Answer (score 1):

So instead of coming up with a regular expression that matches the absence of a string. We might as well just match the selected phrase and append `+` the number of skipped characters.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(str)).matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.start(); i++) sb.append('+');
    sb.append(str);
}
int remaining = input.length() - sb.length();
for (int i = 0; i < remaining; i++) {
    sb.append('+');
}
```

Comment: Is there any point using regex, `indexOf` would also do the trick I feel

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely just for the fun of it, a solution using `CharBuffer` (unexpectedly it took a lot more that I initially hoped for):

```
private static String plusOutCharBuffer(String input, String match) {
    int size = match.length();
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(input.toCharArray());
    CharBuffer word = CharBuffer.wrap(match);

    int x = 0;
    for (; cb.remaining() > 0;) {
        if (!cb.subSequence(0, size < cb.remaining() ? size : cb.remaining()).equals(word)) {
            cb.put(x, '+');
            cb.clear().position(++x);
        } else {
            cb.clear().position(x = x + size);
        }
    }

    return cb.clear().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need a beast of a pattern.  Let's say you you are operating on the following test case as an example:

```
plusOut("abXYxyzXYZ", "XYZ") → "+++++++XYZ"
```

What you need to do is build a series of clauses in your pattern to match a single character at a time:

- Any character that is NOT "X", "Y" or "Z" -- `[^XYZ]`
- Any "X" not followed by "YZ" -- `X(?!YZ)`
- Any "Y" not preceded by "X" -- `(?<!X)Y`
- Any "Y" not followed by "Z" -- `Y(?!Z)`
- Any "Z" not preceded by "XY" -- `(?<!XY)Z`

An example of this replacement can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/jK5wU3/4

Here is an example of how this might work (most certainly not optimized, but it works):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void plusOut(String text, String exclude) {

        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i=0; i<exclude.length(); i++) {

            Character target    = exclude.charAt(i);
            String prefix       = (i > 0) ? exclude.substring(0, i) : "";
            String postfix      = (i < exclude.length() - 1) ? exclude.substring(i+1) : "";

            // add the look-behind (?<!X)Y
            if (!prefix.isEmpty()) {
                pattern.append("(?<!").append(Pattern.quote(prefix)).append(")")
                        .append(Pattern.quote(target.toString())).append("|");
            }

            // add the look-ahead X(?!YZ)
            if (!postfix.isEmpty()) {
                pattern.append(Pattern.quote(target.toString()))
                        .append("(?!").append(Pattern.quote(postfix)).append(")|");
            }

        }

        // add in the other character exclusion
        pattern.append("[^" + Pattern.quote(exclude) + "]");

        System.out.println(text.replaceAll(pattern.toString(), "+"));

    }

    public static void main(String  [] args) {

        plusOut("12xy34", "xy");
        plusOut("12xy34", "1");
        plusOut("12xy34xyabcxy", "xy");
        plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "ab");
        plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "abc");
        plusOut("abXYabcXYZ", "XY");
        plusOut("abXYxyzXYZ", "XYZ");
        plusOut("--++ab", "++");
        plusOut("aaxxxxbb", "xx");
        plusOut("123123", "3");

    }

}
```

UPDATE: Even this doesn't quite work because it can't deal with exclusions that are just repeated characters, like "xx".  Regular expressions are most definitely not the right tool for this, but I thought it might be possible.  After poking around, I'm not so sure a pattern even exists that might make this work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your solution that you put a set of instance string `str.replaceAll("[^str]","+")` which it will exclude any character from the variable `str` and that will not solve your problem

**EX**: when you try `str.replaceAll("[^XYZ]","+")` it will exclude any combination of character `X` , character `Y` and character `Z` from your replacing method so you will get "`++XY+++XYZ`".

Actually you should exclude a sequence of characters instead in `str.replaceAll`.

You can do it by using **capture group** of characters like `(XYZ)` then use a **negative lookahead** to match a string which does not contain characters sequence : `^((?!XYZ).)*$`

Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/5169186) for more info about this problem but you should know that it may be complicated to find regular expression to do that directly.

I have found two simple solutions for this problem :

**Solution 1**:

You can implement a method to replace all characters with '`+`' except the instance of given string:

```
String exWord = "XYZ";
String str = "abXYxyzXYZ";

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    // exclude any instance string of exWord from replacing process in str
    if(str.substring(i, str.length()).indexOf(exWord) + i == i){
        i = i + exWord.length()-1;
    }
    else{
        str = str.substring(0,i) + "+" + str.substring(i+1);//replace each character with '+' symbol
    }
}
```

**Note** : `str.substring(i, str.length()).indexOf(exWord) + i` this if statement will exclude any instance string of `exWord` from replacing process in `str`.

**Output**:

```
+++++++XYZ
```

**Solution 2**:

You can try this Approach using **ReplaceAll** method and it doesn't need any complex regular expression:

```
String exWord = "XYZ";
String str = "abXYxyzXYZ";

str = str.replaceAll(exWord,"*"); // replace instance string with * symbol
str = str.replaceAll("[^*]","+"); // replace all characters with + symbol except * 
str = str.replaceAll("\\*",exWord); // replace * symbol with instance string
```

**Note** : This solution will work only if your input string `str` doesn't contain any `*` symbol.

Also you should escape any character with a special meaning in a regular expression in phrase instance string  `exWord` like : `exWord = "++"`.